# How can I make 2 class instances refer to each other?

Tags: python, class, reference, variable-declaration

So I've been having a bit of an issue with the text-based game I've been making. The game operates by taking a command which references a function, then the function looks for whatever the player's looking for. For example "examine item1" would have it print a description of item1 from the location's dictionary.

The problem I'm having is that I can't set the player's location with my current layout. What I want to happen is the player starts in the cave, enters `go to forest` and the character's location is set to `forest`. However it doesn't get to that point because not matter which way round I declare the two, I hit a NameError. I want to be able to move between the two.

```
cave = location(
    name = "CAVE NAME",
    desc = "It's a cave, there's a forest.",
    objects = {'item1' : item1, 'item2' : item2, 'item3' : item3},
    adjacentLocs = {'forest' : forest}
)
forest = location(
    name = "The Central Forest",
    desc = "It's very woody here. There's a cave.",
    objects = {},
    adjacentLocs = {'cave' : cave}
)
```

Here is my `goTo()` function:

```
def goTo():
    target = None
    #Check inventory
    for key in pChar.inventory:
        if key.name.lower() in pChar.lastInput:
            print("\nThat's an object in your inventory. You won't fit in your backpack.")
            target = key
            break

    #Check scene objects
    if target == None:
        for key, loc in pChar.charLocation.objects.items():
            if key in pChar.lastInput:
                print("\nThat's a nearby object. You have essentially already gone to it.")
                target = key
                break

    #Check location list
    if target == None:
        for key, loc in pChar.charLocation.adjacentLocs.items():
            if key in pChar.lastInput:
                pChar.charLocation = loc
                print("\nYou amble on over to the {}.".format(pChar.charLocation.name))
                target = key
                break

    if target == None:
        print("That place doesn't exist.")
```

How would I best go about referring to the two classes within one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to an object unless it already exists. You could create your locations in two passes: first, initialize them without any adjacent locations. Then, define the adjacent locations. Something like:

```
cave = location(
    name = "CAVE NAME",
    desc = "It's a cave, there's a forest.",
    objects = {'item1' : item1, 'item2' : item2, 'item3' : item3},
    adjacentLocs = {}
)
forest = location(
    name = "The Central Forest",
    desc = "It's very woody here. There's a cave.",
    objects = {},
    adjacentLocs = {}
)

cave.adjacentLocs["forest"] = forest
forest.adjacentLocs["cave"] = cave
```

(This is assuming that location instances assign their adjacent locations to an attribute named `adjacentLocs`. You didn't share your class implementation, so I can't be sure of this detail. Substitute in whatever name is appropriate.)

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. I didn't think to do it in two stages, and yes, adjacentLocs is where they need to run through.